# Valor monetário por extenso em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma alternativa (talvez alguma biblioteca) para escrever valores monetários por extenso em Javascript, por exemplo:

**Input** -> 22,70

**Output** -> Vinte e dois reais e setenta centavos

Comment: Sim, isso responde à minha pergunta. Irei modificar conforme minhas necessidades, muito obrigado